# onClickListener not working that was copied from another working activity

Tags: android, eclipse, button, onclicklistener

I have created a new activity, added it to my manifest file and copy and pasted code from another fully functioning activity yet my buttons do not work when I click on them.  Here is my activity:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;    

public class test extends Activity {

private Button btnChangeDate;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.salesticketoilui);
    mainProgram();
    }

public void mainProgram() {
    btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        } // end onClick
    }); // end setOnClickListener

    Button buttonExit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
    buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
             exitActivity();          
        } // end onClick
    }); // end OnClickListener

    // setup button listener for saving data and exit to main
    Button buttonSaveExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveExit);
    buttonSaveExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveExit();
        } // end onClick
    }); // end OnClickListener

} // end MainProgram ()

    public void saveExit() {
        // does stuff
    }

    public void exitActivity () {
        // does stuff
    }

} // end class
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have shown, it doesn't appear that you ever call the method `mainProgram` so your click listeners will never actually get setup.  Either call `mainProgram` from `onCreate` or just put that code directly into `onCreate`.

Comment: Sorry I accidently left that out of the copy and paste question is updated

Comment: after coping the code to the onCreate the buttons started working. I dont understand why though because it works fine in the other activity. thoughts?

Comment: hmm, no, you should be able to call other methods from onCreate with no problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `onClickListeners` need to go inside of your `onCreate` method.

Comment: In the activity that I copied it from it is working properly with it in the mainProgram() method

Comment: Were you calling the `mainProgram()` method in the other activity? aka: Was anything triggering mainProgram()?

Comment: the mainProgram() method is called from the OnCreate

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Scott

and looks like your missing the @Override

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         exitActivity();          
    } // end onClick
}
```

Make sure your java settings are to 1.6 to avoid code completion missing this.

Comment: In the activity that I copied it from it is working properly without the "@Override"

Comment: `@Override` is not necessary when implementing an interface (which also includes creating an anonymous class from one).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem copying OnClickListener with ImageButtons from a class to another class, and renaming then with bulk copy/paste. 
To make it work, I had to create new buttons in my layout and declare the events manually. Weird!